# TPM 32-bit key handles

Tags: java, tpm

I've been exploring the TPM world and have tried out a few different libraries (i.e. Trousers, jTSS, JSR321, and TPM/J).  Based on a number of requirements [TPM/J](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/tc/tpmj/QuickStartGuide.html) fits the bill and I'm able to accomplish the majority of the operations necessary like binding/unbinding, signing/verifying, etc.

However one issue that I have come across is the key handle.  According to the specs issued by the Trusted Computing Group, [1.2](http://www.trustedcomputinggroup.org/files/static_page_files/72C2B624-1A4B-B294-D0E07C5F7F49140D/TPM%20Main-Part%202%20TPM%20Structures_v1.2_rev116_01032011.pdf) and [2.0](http://www.trustedcomputinggroup.org/files/static_page_files/10437541-1A4B-B294-D0CBCDA0D8979C91/Registry%20of%20Reserved%20TPM%202.0%20Handles%20and%20Localities_v1.0r0.pdf), both declare that key handles are 32-bit values.  When I run TPM/J and I load a key the TPM issues a key OUTSIDE of the 32-bit space.

For example if I run the following command:

```
sudo java edu.mit.csail.tpmj.tools.TPMLoadKey testkey.key SRK ""
```

I receive the following output:

```
Parsing command-line arguments ...

Using SRK as parent.
parentPwd = null, Encoded (NULL [no authorization]) = null

Read testkey.key ...

Loading the key into the TPM ...
keyHandle = 0xc5e94bf9
```

If my calculations (and some online conversion tools I found) are correct then the key handle above computes to 3,320,400,889 which is OUTSIDE 32-bits.  I believe 32-bit signed values are limited to around [2 billion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

This becomes a problem because when I issue the following command:

```
sudo java -cp $CLASSPATH edu.mit.csail.tpmj.tools.TPMUnbind HelloWorld.txt.enc 0xc5e94bf9
```

I get the following output:

```
Parsing command-line arguments ...

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "c5e94bf9"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:484)
    at bayanihan.util.params.Params.getInt(Params.java:67)
    at edu.mit.csail.tpmj.tools.TPMUnbind.main(TPMUnbind.java:71)
```

Just as a sanity check if I use the `TPMUnbind` command above and wait until I load a key that can be handled by Java int type (i.e. falls within 32-bit range) then the command runs just fine.

Has anyone else encountered this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0xc5e94bf9` is a 32 bit number.

In hexadecimal representation one 'digit' represents 4 bits. Thus a 8-bit number ranges from `0x00` to `0xFF`. So 2 hex-digits, also called *nibbles*.

16 bit would be `0x0000` to `0xFFFF`

And your case 32 bit: `0x00000000` to `0xFFFFFFFF`

The link you found for signed integers states `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`. If you interprete this as unsigned, it would be `0` to `4,294,967,296` in decimal representation. Thus `3,320,400,889` is in the range.

---

Now to the error you get: That's a bug in TPM/J. It uses

```
Integer.parseInt( s.substring( 2 ), 16 );
```

to parse the input string. The `parseInt()`-method does not work for hexadecimal numbers larger than `0x7FFFFFFF`.

Comment: Thanks Scolytus for the explanation.  I guess if I want to use this library then I have to change the key handle from int to a long.